# Multiple operations using WITH

Tags: oracle, select, cte

Is there a way to execute multiple operations using the `WITH` statement?

Something like

```
WITH T AS
(
  SELECT * FROM Tbl
)
BEGIN
  OPEN P_OUTCURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM T;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_OUTCOUNT FROM T;
END;
```

I want to select some data and the count of it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can only have one statement after the CTE. You can, however, define subsequent CTEs based on a previous one:

```
WITH t1 AS (
   SELECT a, b, c
   FROM table1
)
, t2 AS (
   SELECT b
   FROM t1
   WHERE a = 5
)
SELECT *
FROM t2;
```

Given that you are trying to count the rows and populate a ref cursor from the same result set, it may be more appropriate to do one of the following:

- create a view
- stage temporary results in a temp table

Finally, if the query is simple enough, just write it once for the count and again for the cursor. Simplicity and readability trump the [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle in this case.

Answer (score 10):

No, a CTE or `with` clause is defined [within the scope of a single statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions)

Sometimes you can do more than you might expect with a single statement though, eg:

```
with w as (select v from t3)
insert all into t1(v) values(v)
           into t2(v) values(v)
select v from w;
```

The 'normal' Oracle way to store temporary result sets (if you have to) is to use a [GTT:

`GLOBAL TEMPORARY` table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54447).