# Is it possible to make a reference to the result of an aggregate function in a SELECT clause from the same SELECT clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, aggregate, syntax

I'm not a Database Administrator--just a Software Engineer. I would like to know if it is possible to reduce the following T-SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(Price * Quantity) as 'Total',
  SUM(Price * Quantity) * 0.95,
FROM
  SomeTables;
```

To something like this:

```
SELECT
  SUM(Price * Quantity) as 'Total',
  'Total' * 0.95,
FROM
  SomeTables;
```

**Note**: This is just a sample to clarify/support my question. My current SQL query is larger and more complex than this.

Comment: Nope. Only your `ORDER BY` clause can reference assigned aliases in the same query. I suggest declaring a CTE that computes the first value, and then computing the second value in a query against that CTE.

Comment: By **CTE** do you mean `Common Table Expression`?

Comment: Yes, [like this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6511/2660).

Comment: @NickChammas - apart from improved readability and maintenance, does CTE improve performance as well in a query like this (on SqlServer)?  In PostgreSQL, the aggregate is computed only once.

Comment: @dezso - Nope. CTEs are mainly used to improve or enable readability, code reuse, and recursive queries.

Comment: It depends what you do in the CTE and what you do in the main query body. In SQL Server anyway, the optimizer is free to pick the most efficient way to run the query, which could include doing things like table spools to cache a temporary result set. If you know that you want something computed only once, I've found it's usually better to use a derived table instead of a CTE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Only your `ORDER BY` clause can reference assigned aliases in the same query.

I suggest declaring a CTE that computes the first value, and then computing the second value in a query against that CTE.

For example:

```
WITH totals AS (
   SELECT SUM(Price * Quantity) AS Total
   FROM   SomeTable
)
SELECT 
     Total
   , (Total * 0.95) AS DiscountedTotal
FROM totals;
```

Think of a CTE as an inline, disposable view. It is valid only for the query that immediately follows it. In that regard, it doesn't give you any performance benefit over doing the same thing with a derived table or with an actual view, or over computing the total twice like in your original query.

Of course, using a CTE *does* have an advantage over calculating the totals twice in two different queries, and it does look cleaner than all the other approaches.

Comment: there is no performance improvement using a `CTE` for my example?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo I think it's still going to be calculated only once.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo - No. Your original query will perform just as well as the CTE I proposed. In this case, the CTE just saves you from retyping your calculation.